# Applescript: Export quicktime audio recording

Tags: audio, applescript, quicktime

With the following applescript, I try to

1. record the audio with "QuickTime Player" for several seconds
2. export the track and save it to the desktop

   ```
   tell application "QuickTime Player"
     launch

     set doku to new audio recording
     start doku
     delay 4
     stop doku
     set savePath to "~/Desktop/record.mp3"
     set newDoc to last item of (documents whose name contains "Untitled")
     export newDoc in file savePath using settings preset "Audio Only"

   end tell
   ```

Creating a new audio recording seems to be quite easy, but for some reason the export-command doesn't work. The error message says, that I don't have the permission to export it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does seem to be a sandboxing issue, but if you move the file path reference out of the QuickTime Player block and into a Finder block, it works. Also, your filename should end in “.m4a” not “.mp3” because QuickTime Player creates MP4 audio files (file extension “.m4a”) not MP3 audio files (file extension “.mp3.”)

So this version of your script works:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set savePath to (the path to the desktop folder as text) & "record.m4a"
    tell application "QuickTime Player"
        activate
        set doku to new audio recording
        start doku
        delay 4
        stop doku
        set newDoc to last item of (documents whose name contains "Untitled")
        export newDoc in file savePath using settings preset "Audio Only"
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error as well.  There is a sandboxing issue.  Try saving it instead to `~/Movies/` and your code should work okay.  Then you can move it around using other commands to the folder you want it to be in.

Comment: Seemed to be a good idea, but anyway it didn't work for me...But thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I found a [solution to a related issue](https://discussions.apple.com/message/25522882#message25522882) on the Apple Communities forum.

Instead of:

```
set savePath to "~/Desktop/record.mp3"
```

try separating the path components with a `:`, like:

```
set savePath to "Macintosh HD:Users:<your username>:Desktop:record.mp3"
```